# How to set data in RecyclerView on Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want get some data from server and show it into `Recyclerview`. I can show this data, but some time not show this data and just show progressBar.
I show this data in `Log.e` and show **fastly**, but not show this data in `RecyclerView` and just show Progress.
**Please see below picture to know my mean :** 
[Click too see](https://s8.postimg.org/i58gcazg5/image.jpg)

**My Response codes:**

```
InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
Call<CountryResponse> call = api.getCountryList();

call.enqueue(new Callback<CountryResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<CountryResponse> call, Response<CountryResponse> response) {
        try {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                models.clear();
                models.addAll(response.body().getData());
                for (int i = 0; i <= models.size(); i++) {
                    Log.e("CountryInfoTAG", response.body().getData().get(i).getId() + " : " +
                            response.body().getData().get(i).getName());
                }

                countryProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                countryRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<CountryResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        Toasty.error(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.failRequest),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG, true).show();
    }
});
```

**Adapter codes:**

```
public class CountryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List<CountryDatum> mData;
    private Context context;
    private sendDataListener listner;

    public CountryAdapter(List<CountryDatum> mData, Context context, sendDataListener listner) {
        this.mData = mData;
        this.context = context;
        this.listner = listner;

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_country, parent, false);
        vh = new DataViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (holder instanceof DataViewHolder) {
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).countryListTxt.setText(mData.get(position).getName() + "");
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).countryListTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listner.onSendIdName(mData.get(position).getId(), mData.get(position).getName());

                    if (context instanceof RegisterActivity) {
                        ((RegisterActivity) context).dismissCountryDialog();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public void add(List<CountryDatum> models) {
        mData.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clear() {
        mData.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView countryListTxt;

        public DataViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            countryListTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.countryNameTxt);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix? please help me. 
How can I fix? please help me

Comment: it depends on internet connection speed, some times it takes more time because of slow network, and reason for fast display of data in logcat is that in logcat your are just showing data in terminal, where as in recycler view there is a UI, and it will display data when all the data is populated

Comment: @AbdulKawee, if internet connection speed is slow not show data in LogCat! why show in logcat and not show in recyclerview? how can i speed up show data into recyclerview? can you help me?

Comment: Check the line of your code its in the loop, means with every record the log will show as soon as the record is received , where as in the recycler view it will only show the data when it is completely received

Comment: Completed data is a few time in logcat. but not show in recyclerview. data is loaded fastly in logcat

Comment: set the adapter to recycle view in oncreate method. In onResponse method fill up the mData list and call "mAdapter.notifydatasetchanged()"

Answer (score 0):

Well Try this, you are not initializing the adapter object in success response.
Add this `mAdapter = new CountryAdapter(models,getActivity(),listener);`

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(Call<CountryResponse> call, Response<CountryResponse> response) {
        try {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                models.clear();
                models.addAll(response.body().getData());
                for (int i = 0; i <= models.size(); i++) {
                    Log.e("CountryInfoTAG", response.body().getData().get(i).getId() + " : " +
                            response.body().getData().get(i).getName());
                }

                countryProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mAdapter = new CountryAdapter(models,getActivity(),listener);
                countryRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, but i initialize adapter in onCreate metyhod. in my above codes show some time data into recyclerview and not show some time. some time show and some time not show !!! how can i fix it?

Comment: @Dongle , you are having data in onSuccess, how can you initialize adapter in onCreate()

Comment: its because when sometimes it load quickly and shows data and sometimes not , beacuse u dont call adapter again the api returns data

Comment: @quicklearner, thanks my friend, if i initialize again adapter in onSuccess fix my problem and show data everytime into recyclerview?

Comment: Just try it and do let me know